# How to Persist a prometheus count on a pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Currently we are using [Grafana](https://grafana.com) for our basic dashboarding but would like to do a bit more, namely having a persistent count across multiple application restarts.

We do releases hourly on a various micro-services (c#), so persistence of these metrics is needed to get good statistics from those services.

Is there anyway to persist it cross restart?

Comment: Do you have access to an fileserver from inside the pods?

Comment: Surely Prometheus persists the metrics it gathers – maybe this is more about the labeling of those metrics?

Comment: @M.B. there are multiple ways I can store data, but my main question is how to persist the count. I could use persistent volumes within my cluster, so there are ways to store it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prometheus, but if i were to store metrics i would look for a server that is up and running 24/7. Store the data in a database or save it on a fileserver